# Procedure with Cursor for E-Mail

Tags: sql, ssms

i have a table with following things inside:

```
Name E-Mail
Trump, Donald Null
```

Now i have to do a Procedure with a cursor, which creates a e-mail out of the name of the guy.
f.e. `donald.trump@usa.com`, also it should update the e-mail table.

How can  i do this?

Comment: Can you please share the expected output and current ouput. as per your question you want to perform concat operation?

Comment: @jishansiddique i don't really understand, what you mean. Actually the name is in one  column as name, firstname.
The e-Mail column should become firstname.name@usa.com. All as a procedure with cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this example created as per your requirement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [NameProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @table AS TABLE
(
    Name NVARCHAR(200),
    Email NVARCHAR(200) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @table(Name) VALUES('Trump, Donald'),('barack, obama')

    DECLARE 
    @nameemail NVARCHAR(20)   

    DECLARE cursor_procedure CURSOR
    FOR SELECT 
           REPLACE(Name,',','') AS Name
        FROM
        (
            SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(Name,CHARINDEX(',',Name)),'.',RIGHT(Name,CHARINDEX(',',Name)),'@usa.com') Name       
            FROM @table
        ) AS Result


    OPEN cursor_procedure;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_procedure INTO 
        @nameemail
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @nameemail AS Name
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_procedure INTO 
                @nameemail            
        END;
    CLOSE cursor_procedure;
DEALLOCATE cursor_procedure;
END


-- Run the store procedure 
EXEC [NameProcedure]
```

> Output

[image]

For cursor related you can read this

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-cursor/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL server

```
select CONCAT (SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(',', name)  + 1, LEN(name)) , '.' , LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(',', name) - 1) , '@usa.com')  from 
(
select 'Trump, Donald' as name 
)  tab
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i need to use a procedure with cursor. it was a task at a exam last year and i try to understand how it works.

Comment: It isn't. I just try to understand the task from the exam last year, so i can get trough the exam this year. I had a lot problems with cursors.